# variable does not recognized by ansible while calling role with variable

Tags: ansible

top_level_main.yml

```
roles:
 - { role: deploy_nds }
```

roles/deploy_nds/vars/main.yml

```
artifact_url: urlsomething
```

roles/deploy_nds/meta/main.yml

```
dependencies:
- {role: download_artifact, url: artifact_url }
```

roles/download_artifactory/tasks/main.yml

```
  - name: download artifact from jfrog
    get_url:
         url: "{{ url }}"
         dest: /var/tmp
```

I tried using variable name as "{{ artifact_url }}" but still it does not work as expect. Can someone please help?

Comment: Is the role not executed or only the variable undefined? If actually the first, that's because the role name is download_artifactory but you include download_artifact. Other than that I don't see an issue, should work with `{{ artifact_url }}`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We're having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have explicitly included vars file of perticular role in playbook then it worked.

```
vars_files:
   - roles/deploy_nds/vars/main.yml
roles:
   - { role: deploy_nds }
```